# Is there a shaderless way to draw multiple points with different sizes using glDrawArrays()?

Tags: opengl

I'm drawing a point cloud with different colors of points with this:

```
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);


    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices.get());
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors.get());


    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, n);


    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

is there a way to tell glDrawArrays (or the default shader) to use another client state for size of each point?

Comment: There is no default shader. And the fixed function pipeline (deprecated for several years) does not support individual point sizes. You should not use it anyway unless you have a good reason to do so.

Comment: I searched for a hello-world of VBO for point clouds but couldn't find any info. Then saw this and worked but without size unfortunately. Do you mean deprecated fixed function pipeline is used when `glDrawArrays` or `glEnableClientState` is used? Before this, I was using immediate mode with smooth point size and correct auto z-ordering. But immediate mode is way too slow for a million points.

Comment: As soon as you don't have a shader bound, OpenGL will try to use the fixed function pipeline if it is still available. This does not work if you have a core profile context. So, in short: Always use a shader.

Comment: What kind of question should I ask for a minimal shader example for glDrawArrays with GL_POINTS? What should I use? Vertex shader or fragment shader or something else?

Comment: You will need both shaders. I would suggest to take a look at an arbitrary tutorial for model rendering (with modern OpenGL). If you know how to do this, then switching to pointclouds is simply a matter of replacing `GL_TRIANGLES` with `GL_POINTS`. More or less...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there was, that would be terribly inefficient!

1. Use the programmable pipeline, in a core context => OpenGL 3.3 and above.
2. Create a buffer with all your vertices (your points).
3. Create a buffer with the sizes of each point.
4. Pass buffers 2 and 3 to your vertex shader. Assign the size to the global gl_PointSize.

If you don't get what I am suggesting, you must then begin by learning the modern OpenGL way of rendering :)

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get past size-less version of shaders now doing this size array extension. Doesn't accept, maybe I'm on GL 3.0-.

Comment: Ok, now it works with `glEnable( GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE );`, thank you. So many states to manage! :] Also added `#version 330` at first line, just in case it compiles for different version.